# Why using rs:Command=Render in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I notice I can use both links to display the SSRS report in Browser. So why using rs:Command=Render?

https://myrshost/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory&**rs:Command=Render**

https://myrshost/reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesByCategory

Answer (score 1):

If you do not include it, then the server will determine the default action to take. According to the documentation there may be slight performance benefits to doing this.

> **[Access report server items by using URL access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/access-report-server-items-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver16)**
> It is not necessary to actually add this parameter string. If you omit it, the report server evaluates the item type and selects the appropriate parameter value automatically. However, using the rs:Command=Value string in the URL improves the performance of the report server.